# How do I log into a new virtualbox debian machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian

I just created a debian machine in virtualbox and selected an existing virtual hard drive. When I start the VM, it asks me for a login, but I haven't been able to find any information on what the default user and password is for this. Where can I find the default login info?

Comment: @Ramhound The virtual hard drive that apparently comes with virtualbox has the system already installed, so there is *some* login info I'd be expected to use there, otherwise why would they even give you the option of booting from that VHD? Also, your last sentence isn't valid English.

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't come with a virtual hdd. We do not know the password to this user that doesn't normally exist if you actually install the OS yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default user, you (or someone else) created a user during install. By default root does not have a password so you cannot log into that user in the standard way.

However, If you forgot the user/password you provided during install you can easily recover this by booting into single user mode, *this will not work if someone has changed root password*, but this is not a concern in a fresh system.

1. Reboot PC
2. Hold `SHIFT` key during boot in order to interrupt GRUB

[image: Grub Screen]

3. Click `e` to edit (**this is not permanent**)
4. Scroll down in the edit window to the line that start with `linux ....`
5. Add one character - `1` to the end of this line. 
   [image]
6. Press `F10` to continue boot, press `enter` when asked if you want recovery mode.
7. You should be in a root shell, `ls /home` , the user you create should have a directory there

   - alternatively, create a new user with `adduser`
8. Change the passwd for your user `passwd user`
9. Reboot and use your login info.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem just now, the correct answer is:

- **username**: `vboxuser`
- **password**: `changeme`